# how to highlight double sentences on a line using vim

Tags: vim, double, highlight

I would like to know if it is possible to highlight double sentences on a line using vim (highlighting as after doing a search).

*example*:

This is my first line. This is my first line.
this is my second line this is my second line
"more text" this is my third line "more text" this is my third line "more text" this is my third line

---

*highlight all double sentences --> output: (highlighting in bold):*

**This is my first line.** "more text" **This is my first line.**
**this is my second line this is my second line**
"more text" **this is my third line** "more text" **this is my third line** "more text" **this is my third line**

---

*highlight all but first double --> output: (highlighting in bold)*

This is my first line. "more text" **This is my first line.**
this is my second line **this is my second line**
"more text" this is my third line "more text" **this is my third line** "more text" **this is my third line**

---

> a double sentence is a piece of text with 2 or more similar words in
>   the same sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The Vim tip [Highlight doubled word errors in text](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_doubled_word_errors_in_text) has a regular expression that does this for duplicate words; you can maybe extend this to capture whole sentences.

But I doubt that you can come up with one that covers all your requirements, is still somewhat maintainable, and doesn't drag down Vim's performance. *(But let that be a challenge to you and others!)*

Comment: I use this one to highlight double words: `\(\<\w\+\)\_s\+\1\><CR>:set hls<CR>` Havent found a way to search double sentences.

Comment: @Remonn: Yes, that's almost identical to the one in the tip.

Answer (score 1):

To highlight all double sentences you can use

/This is my first line\|this is my second line\|this is my third line

I dont know how to highlight all but first double

Comment: I think the poster mean arbitrary sentences; these were just examples.

Comment: Yes, they were just examples. Last week, I had a file with in every line a double sentences. They were all different. Over 800 lines.